# I want the game to end when the phrase has been guessed. Also the player cycle does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to rotate the current player back to player1 when player3 makes a wrong guess. Currently, when player 3 makes a wrong guess it crashes and says:
IndexError: list index out of range.
How would this be fixed?

### Also if I guess all the letters in the phrase it does do anything. I would like the feedback text to change to "Good job you guessed the phrase"

```
from tkinter import *
import random

phrase_list = []
# phrases_text = open("phrases.txt").read().splitlines()
phrases_text = open("phrases.txt").read().splitlines()
for phrase in phrases_text:
    phrase_list.append(phrase)
    phrase = random.choice(phrase_list)
guessed = []
players_score = {}
players = []
current_player = 0
prizes = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
prize = random.choice(prizes)


guessed.clear()


def incorrect():
    global current_player
    current_player += 1


def player_assign():
    for i in range(1, 4):
        p_name = "Player" + str(i)
        players.append(p_name)
        players_score[p_name] = 0
        text99.set(players_score)





def check_phrase():
    global current_player
    text5.set("Its " + players[current_player] + " s turn")
    if current_player >= len(players):
        current_player = 0

    place_holder = ""

    guess = str(entry_window.get()).lower()

    def points():
        prize_assign = phrase.count(guess) * prize
        players_score[players[current_player]] += prize_assign
        text88.set(prize)
        text99.set(players_score)

    if guess == phrase:
        text.set("Good job you guessed the phrase")
    elif guess in guessed:
        text.set("You already guessed that letter")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

    elif len(guess) > 1:
        text.set("Sorry that was not the phrase")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

        text5.set("The turn for " + players[current_player])

    elif guess in phrase:
        text.set("Good job, the letter " + str(guess) + " is in the phrase")
        guessed.append(guess)
        points()
        entry_window.delete(0, END)


    elif guess.isalpha() is False:
        text.set("Please do not enter special characters or numbers")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

    elif text2 == place_holders:
            text96.set("good")

    else:
        text.set("No, the letter " + str(guess) + " is not in the phrase")
        guessed.append(guess)
        entry_window.delete(0, END)
        incorrect()
    for char in phrase:
        if char == " ":
            place_holder = place_holder + " "
        elif char in guessed:
            place_holder = place_holder + char
            text2.set(place_holder)
        else:
            place_holder = place_holder + "_ "
            text2.set(place_holder)
    i = ",".join(guessed)
    text3.set("Letters guessed: " + i)


# Main GUI
root = Tk()
root.title("Wheel of Fortune")
root.geometry("500x300")

# Label to instruct the user on what to do.
label = Label(root, text="Welcome to weel of Fortune \n"
              "Guess a letter in the phrase, or guess the "
              "whole phrase")
label.pack()

text5 = StringVar()
text5.set("Its Player 1s turn")
player_rotation = Label(root,  textvariable=text5)
player_rotation.pack()

# User input box
entry_window = Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=5)
entry_window.pack()

# Check button to check the phrase
button_check = Button(root, text="Check", command=check_phrase)
button_check.pack()

# Creating a text variable which changes depending on the users input
text = StringVar()
text.set("")
feedback_text = Label(root,  textvariable=text)
feedback_text.pack()

# Creating a text variable which prints the letters placeholders/underscores
text2 = StringVar()
text2.set("_ "*len(phrase))
place_holders = Label(root,  textvariable=text2)
place_holders.pack()

# Creating a text variable which show the guessed letters
text3 = StringVar()
text3.set("Letters guessed: ")
place_holders = Label(root,  textvariable=text3)
place_holders.pack()

# Creating a text variable which shows the players and the points
text99 = StringVar()
text99.set(" iii")
score = Label(root,  textvariable=text99)
score.pack()

text88 = StringVar()
text88.set(" eee")
wheel = Label(root,  textvariable=text88)
wheel.pack()

text96 = StringVar()
text96.set(" eeppp")
wheel = Label(root,  textvariable=text96)
wheel.pack()

place_holders.pack()
player_assign()


# Exit button to exit the program
button_exit = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
button_exit.pack()

# Main loop for the whole GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two segments out of order:

```
text5.set("Its " + players[current_player] + " s turn")
if current_player >= len(players):
    current_player = 0
```

This checks to see if `current_player` is out of the range of `players` AFTER it's been used in the `players` list! Put the if statement before the text5.set and it should work.

To answer your second question, you're comparing `guess` to `phrase`, which is not desirable, since the contestant only enters a single number at a time,
I've modified your `check_phrase` function to instead check the `placeholder` against your `phrase` variables and got it to respond correctly:

```
def check_phrase():
    global current_player
    if current_player >= len(players):
        current_player = 0
    text5.set("Its " + players[current_player] + " s turn")

    place_holder = ""

    guess = str(entry_window.get()).lower()

    def points():
        prize_assign = phrase.count(guess) * prize
        players_score[players[current_player]] += prize_assign
        text88.set(prize)
        text99.set(players_score)

    if guess in guessed:
        text.set("You already guessed that letter")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

    elif len(guess) > 1:
        text.set("Sorry that was not the phrase")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

        text5.set("The turn for " + players[current_player])

    elif guess in phrase:
        text.set("Good job, the letter " + str(guess) + " is in the phrase")
        guessed.append(guess)
        points()
        entry_window.delete(0, END)


    elif guess.isalpha() is False:
        text.set("Please do not enter special characters or numbers")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

    elif text2 == place_holders:
            text96.set("good")

    else:
        text.set("No, the letter " + str(guess) + " is not in the phrase")
        guessed.append(guess)
        entry_window.delete(0, END)
        incorrect()
    for char in phrase:
        if char == " ":
            place_holder = place_holder + " "
        elif char in guessed:
            place_holder = place_holder + char
            text2.set(place_holder)
        else:
            place_holder = place_holder + "_ "
            text2.set(place_holder)
    if place_holder == phrase:
        text2.set('Good job you guessed the phrase: '+place_holder)
        
    i = ",".join(guessed)
    text3.set("Letters guessed: " + i)
```

For future questions, please limit your code to the pertaining sections, include the stack trace to help debuggers, and see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).